# JSF валидация файла с последующей загрузкой

Tags: jsf

JSF.

Нужно сделать
Файл генерируется на стороннем сервере по запросу. Нужно проверить: если размер файла > определённого значения (не пустой), то вывести пользователю диалог о загрузке, если нет, то перекинуть на страницу с ошибкой.

Пробую так, но файл не загружается (ещё новичок в JSF)

```
<p:commandButton action="#{ManBean.getReport}" ajax="false"
                                 onclick="target='_blank'" onmouseout="target='_self'"
                                 value="Получить файл"></p:commandButton>
 public String getReport() {

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    File file = null;
    String url = null;

    try {
        // Получаем директорию для временных файлов
        String tempDirectoryName = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "\\ZZZ";
        File tempDirectory = new File(tempDirectoryName);
        tempDirectory.mkdir();

        // Удаляем все временные файлы, которые созданы за прошлые дни
        File[] tempFiles = tempDirectory.listFiles();
        Date date = new Date();
        for (File tempFile : tempFiles) {
            Date lastModified = new Date(tempFile.lastModified());
            if (lastModified.getDay() != date.getDay())
                tempFile.delete();
        }

        // Загружаем файл и проверям по размеру то, что он не пустой
        url = "http://Некий запрос";
        URL website = new URL(url);
        String formType = "Некий тип";
        ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        String fileName = tempDirectory + "\" + formType + ".rtf";
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        fileOutputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        fileOutputStream.close();
        file = new File(fileName);
        if (file.length() < 33000)
            return "./zzz/error.xhtml";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        try {
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    return "doDownload?url=" + url;
}
```

Comment: Сами же пишите, что должен вывестись диалог загрузки (doDownload?), а не загрузка. Или по вашей задумке doDownload должен начать автоматическую загрузку? Что из себя представляет doDownload?

Comment: если вставить в строку браузера "doDownload?url=какой-то_url, то появляется диалог загрузки, я оттакливался от этого

Comment: в моём же случае ничего не происходит

Comment: 1) doDownload - тоже JSF? (должен быть JSF) 2) См. лог. может exception происходит, не зря же ловушек понаставили. 3) onclick="target='_blank'" onmouseout="target='_self'" никогда такого не видел. вдруг так нельзя и уже в браузере клик не срабатывает? браузерные ошибки можно посмотреть в консоли разработчика браузера 4) commandbutton в form-е?

Comment: в браузерной консоли ошибок нет